# Плавная анимация WinForms / C#

Tags: c#, winforms

День добрый. Подскажите, как на WinForms сделать плавную анимацию, желательно с управлением ее скорости.
Код, который я использую для анимации:

```
animBW.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    while (true) {
        int width = panel1.Width;
        //Random r = new Random();

        if (width < this.Width) {
            int newwidth = width++;
            setWidth(newwidth);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Но при Thread.Sleep(1) анимация слишком медленная, да и зависит от размера объекта. (больше объект => больше ждать, это понятно)

При отсутствии паузы анимация вовсе не видна.

Подскажите, как сделать анимацию независимой от размера блока и более быстрой?

Answer (score 6):

Я советую использовать класс `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` для таких целей. Создайте таймер, задайте интервал в миллисекундах через который будет генерироваться событие `Tick`. Событию присвойте обработчик, в котором накапливайте число шагов (например в статическую переменную). Если оно превысило нужное вам, то останавливайте таймер. Пример кода вам в помощь.

```
private void mainForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 30; // каждые 30 миллисекунд
            int count = 0;
            int max = 10;
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x, y, 10, 10);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler((o, ev) =>
            {
                x += 5;
                y += 5;
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x, y, 10, 10);
                count++;

                if (count == max)
                {
                    Timer t = o as Timer; // можно тут просто воспользоваться timer
                    t.Stop();
                }
            });
            timer.Start();   // запустили, а остановится он сам                              
        }
```

Этот код по клику двигает кружок на пустой форме.
Если вы хотите, например, всегда за 1 секунду рисовать анимацию, то соответсвенно берите всегда интервал, скажем, 10 миллисекунд и 100 шагов, а параметры изображения меняйте на 1/100 от общего изменения (разность между началом и концом анимации) за каждый шаг. Можно еще снижать частоту перерисовки для маленьких объектов, но это уже на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую чуть позже..

Comment: Анимация осталась такой же резкой и не красивой. Таймер работает так же как и thread.sleep()

Comment: @AGrief анимация из 15 кадров обычно уже смотрится нормально. Вы же можете сделать 1000 кадров в секунду. Ваша проблема, я думаю, не в раскадровке анимации, а в скорости отрисовки. Например, приведенный мной пример рисуется не очень хорошо (часть кадров не видна, изображение дергается), на pictureBox c применением Bitmap он будет гораздо лучше. Вы же хотите, как я понимаю, перерисовывать контрол, который возможно долго себя перерисовывает и в итоге пропускает частично кадры, а все вместе мерцает.

Answer (score 4):

От мерцания защитит Double Buffering, для плавности используют Multimedia Timers(Windows API).